# How to convert a Dictionary to QuerySet in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, pagination, django-filter

I've converted a Django queryset("rueckgabeliste") into a Dictionary(mydict). The key is my Django object and the value is a calculation. Afterwards I had sorted my Dictionary by the value. Now I need to reconvert the sorted Dictionary to a Format, which is the same like the initially type (Queryset).
It's importanted that the order keeps remaining after reconverting due to the fact that I want to use it with my pagination and the django-filters 1.1.0 app as a sidebar filter.

```
rueckgabeliste = Adventure.objects.filter(pk__in=trefferliste)


    mydict={}

    for x in rueckgabeliste:
                    mydict[x] = ...  

    ...calculation...
```

next up you can see my ordering

`mydict = sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (v,k): (k,v),reverse=True)`

and on the following you can see my pagination, but I want to use "mydict" instead of "filter_rueckgabeliste". Futhermore "filter_rueckgabeliste" is my statement for my sidebar-filter which is working with "rueckgabeliste" but I also want to hand over "mydict" instead of "rueckgabeliste".

```
filter_rueckgabeliste = AdventureFilter(request.GET, queryset=rueckgabeliste)



    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(filter_rueckgabeliste.qs, 5) # Show 5 contacts per page

    try:
            response = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            response = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            response = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Thanks for any Help